# how to input the parent id into database in different table

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have table -> subkategori

[image: subkategori]

and I can't insert the id_kategori attribute to table portfolio

[image: portofolio]

i have a code for the model :

```
function get_subcategories($id_kategori){

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_kategori from subkategori WHERE id_subkategori=".$this->input->post('a'));
return $query->result();
}
```

and the controller here :

```
if ($this->input->post('a')!=''){
    $this->load->model('Model_app');
    $this->model_app->get_subcatoegories('$id_kategori');
}else{
    $id_kategori = '';
}
$data = array(
            'id_subkategori'=>$this->db->escape_str($this->input->post('a')),
            'id_kategori'=>$id_kategori
        );
```

Comment: I think a little more information is required to answer your question. 
Maybe you can add the database table structure into your question?

Comment: where is your insert query and what about id_portfolio ? Do you want only  'id_subkategori' and 'id_kategori' need to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$this->input->post('a')` as you mentioned here I assume that you have input in the form and its name is `a`.

**In Controller**

```
if (!empty($this->input->post('a')))
{
    $this->load->model('Model_app');
    $id = $this->model_app->get_subcatoegories($this->input->post('a'));

    if (empty($id)) {
        $id_kategori = '';
    } else {
        $id_kategori = $id[0]['id_kategori'];
    }

}else{
    $id_kategori = '';
}

$data = array(
    'id_subkategori'=>$this->db->escape_str($this->input->post('a')),
    'id_kategori'=>$id_kategori
);
```

**In Model**

```
function get_subcategories($id_kategori)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_kategori FROM subkategori WHERE id_subkategori = $id_kategori");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

---

You can get last insterted if with `$this->db->insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

In your, if statement you didn't assign the database value to the `$id_kategori` variable. Hence while inserting the empty value into the table it inserts as 0(int field).

And also when you pass a variable to a function it should not be single quoted. You have to pass the post variable but you are passing a variable which is undefined.

```
if ($this->input->post('a')!=''){
    $this->load->model('Model_app');
    $category = $this->model_app->get_subcatoegories($this->input->post('a'));
    $id_kategori = $category['id_kategori];
}else{
    $id_kategori = '';
}
$data = array(
            'id_subkategori'=>$this->db->escape_str($this->input->post('a')),
            'id_kategori'=>$id_kategori
        );
```